# Candid people shots

Tags: legal

What are the appropriate laws regarding taking candid or unsolicited shots of people in public places? Do they have a right to prohibit me from doing so? Can they sue me for invasion of privacy? Do they own the photos or have copyright to them? What are my rights and privileges?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I photograph people publicly, in the USA, without their consent?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/25876/can-i-photograph-people-publicly-in-the-usa-without-their-consent)

Comment: Laws can vary quite a lot by country - which country are you concerned with?

Answer (score 2):

if its in a public space you kinda have free reign, kinda.

http://content.photojojo.com/tips/legal-rights-of-photographers/

if you want to move beyond public space you should have a [model release](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_release) handy